# Connect to Stack Overflow API

Tags: c#

I am trying to connect to the Stack Overflow API as one of my first api calls, but I am struggling.

Can someone tell me why this code does not return a success code?

```
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler())
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.stackexchange.com/");
            var response = await client.GetAsync("questions");

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
            }
}
```

Comment: What code does it return?

Comment: have you tried hitting `http://api.stackexchange.com/questions` in your browser?  It gives you a 400

Comment: `{"error_id":400,"error_message":"site is required","error_name":"bad_parameter"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response tells you `site` is required. Hit `https://api.stackexchange.com/questions?site=stackoverflow` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting back

```
{"error_id":400,"error_message":"site is required","error_name":"bad_parameter"}
```

If you read the error and documentation, it needs to know which StackExchange site you want. Try:

`https://api.stackexchange.com/questions?site=stackoverflow`